# How do I initialize an eager singleton without requiring a controller request in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

In a Scala-based Play application, I'm trying to initiate a singleton service without requiring a request to a controller. I've followed the directions in the [2.4 API documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings) to create a singleton class and then use Guice's dependency injection library to bind the class as an **eager** singleton.

Even with eager binding, the singleton still doesn't get called until after I've received a request through a controller route. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

## Module

```
package models

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.name.Names

class MessageLogModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[MessageLogService]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

## Configuration

```
play.modules.enabled += "models.MessageLogModule"
```

## Singleton

```
package models

import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class MessageLogService {
  // Create a file to test
  println("IN SINGLETON - CREATING NEW FILE")
  val file = new java.io.File("howdy.txt")
  file.createNewFile
}
```

## Run Command

```
sbt compile run
```

The above singleton does not get called until I issue a...

```
curl http://localhost:9000/
```

What I want is for MessageLogService to start at the point of running the service and not wait for a request to hit a controller route.

Comment: Did you try "sbt compile start"? Run does some tricks during development.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Awesome! That was it! Can you post that as an official answer so I can make it as 'Answered' and give you the credit?

Comment: For anyone else who runs across this, here is a post that discusses the differences between `run` and `start`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213427/what-are-the-differences-between-play-run-and-start

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is: `sbt compile start`

`run` delays compilation and initialization until first request to allow for faster change-refresh-see-change development cycle.